# If $X_n\nearrow X$ then $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, means, almost-everywhere

Let $(X_n)$ be an increasing sequence of real valued integrable rvs on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, such that $(X_n)$ converges ae to some rv $X$. Is it true that $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)$?

Some thoughts: Ι guess not. If $X_n$'s were positive then we could apply the monotone convergence theorem, but now we are looking for a counterexample. I am working on $[0,1]$, equipped with the Lebesgue measure and looking for discrete rvs that do the job, but no matter how I change their formula, I seem not to be getting the desired non-convergence.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: split the random variable up into positive and negative parts and apply the monotone convergence theorem to each.

Comment: @user159517 which could give you $\infty-\infty$

Comment: @user159517, you claim that since $X_n \rightarrow X$ ae, then $X_n^{+}\rightarrow X^{+}$ and $X_{n}^{-}\rightarrow X^{-}$? (if that holds, then things are a bit straightforward, since $X_n^{+}\nearrow X^{+},~X_n^{-}\nearrow X^{-}$ and all the rvs are positive valued).

Comment: The sequence $X_n-X_1$ of non-negative, integrable random variables increases to $X-X_1.$

Comment: Not an answer, but shouldn't this be true for weaker condition ($X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability/measure), by absolute continuity of integral w.r.t. measure?

Comment: @frank000 not sure about it. Also not sure if that would work somehow for the ae converge that have to work on.

Comment: I think you could propose a definition of for the convergence of a sequence of random variables. Given that definition, it should be possible to work out a proof in case the claim is true or at least find some insight on why it wouldn't be. For instance, can I assume that for any $ε>0$ there should exist $n(ε)$ such that $E[(X_n−X)^2]<ε$ ?

Answer (score 4):

You said that the variables $X_n$ are integrable.  This means that $E |X_n| < \infty$ for all $n$. Then $X_n - X_1$ make an increasing sequence of nonnegative random variables.  By monotone convergence theorem,
$$
E(X_n - X_1) \to E \lim_{n\to\infty}(X_n - X_1) = E X - E X_1\qquad (1)
$$
with finite $E X_1$. ($E X$ is either finite or is equal to $+\infty$).  The desired convergence is obtained by adding $E X_1$ to both sides of (1).

If $X_n$ are measurable, but not necessarily integrable,
then we can construct a counterexample. Let $U$ be a random variable uniformly distributed on $(0, 1)$. Let
$$
X_n = \begin{cases} 
-1/U & \text{if}~ U < 1/n, \\
0    & \text{if}~ U \ge 1/n.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ is increasing in $n$ (surely) and is converging to $0$ (surely).  But $E X_n = -\infty$ for all $n$, and $E 0 = 0$. Thus, $E X_n$ do not tend to $E \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n$.